# console.log in flask with javasript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pycharm

I want to print some string, for example, "Hello World". I use javasript with  flask in pycharm for it:

```
 <script>
        function hello()
        {
            alert("Hello!!!!");
        }

 </script>
```

in html

```
<button onclick="hello()">Click button!</button>
```

It works well. But when I try to change from `alert` to `console.log` the code does not work at all. THe code should have result as `print("Hello World")` in python.

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: How did you came to the conclusion that the code does not work, if i may ask ? Did you check your browser console ?

Comment: I need to print it in pycharm console

Comment: That's not how the `console.log` works. They are in browser(in this case) territory now. Also why do you need it to print in the pycharm console ? You could just check the browser console, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you press f12 you'll access the developer tools on the browser. there you'll see it's own console. that's where the message would appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly see the result on the HTML document,
you can use:

```
  document.write("Hello!!!");
  document.writeln("Hello!!!");
```

but if you want to log it in developer tools section(you can reach it by right click on the web page and choose "Inspect" or you can simply press F12 on chrome, firefox, edge), use the following code:

```
console.log("Hello!!!");
console.warn("Hello!!!")
```

Here's a simple snippet help you understand.

```js
function hello() {
  console.log("This is a logged message at the console.");
  console.warn("This is a logged message at the console with warning tag");
  document.write("Here you can print the result on the web page");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Click button!</button>
```